# python-tornado chatdemo on heroku

Tags: python, heroku, websocket, tornado, sockjs

I am new to python-tornado. I tried the chat demo on tornado.org. It works perfectly on my localhost; however, After deploying it onto heroku, I can't get the message(chat with 2 browsers) only if I refresh the browser.The demo site is here https://tornadochat2.herokuapp.com
and the demo code:https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/blob/stable/demos/chat/chatdemo.py
My Procfile is as below 
    `web: python chat.py --port=$PORT`
I have no idea what's going on of it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't work because you're accessing it using https:// but you're trying to load jquery using http://. If you check out your browser's error console you'll see the error that's preventing jquery library to load. This is known as [Mixed Content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Security/MixedContent).

Noltice that it works if you go to http://tornadochat2.herokuapp.com/ (not using https).

In order to make it work, just change this html code in `templates/index.html`:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

for:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: thanks a lot !!! I did notice jquery didn't work but have no idea  what's going on